# jupyter labextension install of qgrid failed on optional dependency (windows)

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, jupyter-lab, qgrid

When I try `jupyter labextension install qgrid` it fails, and the core error in the log file is the following:

```
$ webpack --config webpack.prod.minimize.config.js
[webpack-cli] ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'base/js/dialog'
```

The context in which this error occurs is so complicated it is kind of funny:

Windows 10 >> Conda environment >> jupyter labextension install >> npm >> node yarn.js run >> webpack

Everything from the conda environment on down is newly installed as of two days ago.  (jupyter lab version 3.0.9, node version v14.16.0)

What is particularly interesting about the error is that the only reference to `base/js/dialog` in the code is this statement from `qgrid.widget.js`:

```
try {
  dialog = require('base/js/dialog');
} catch (e) {
  console.warn("Qgrid was unable to load base/js/dialog. " +
               "Full screen button won't be available");
}
```

Now I don't know how `webpack` works, but it seems that somehow the optional load is causing a hard failure.   I'm looking for any insight on how to tackle this error.

(Additional note: I also tried `jupyter lab build` just in case that would magically fix things, but it resulted in the same error.)

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely caused by the **qgrid** not being updated to work with JypyterLab 3. There are several related issues at https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid e.g. [#351](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid/issues/351).

Unfortunately this extension doesn't seem to be updated that regularly. If you don't want to stay on J2 then you can have a look at [perspective](https://perspective.finos.org/docs/md/python.html) or [ipyaggrid](https://gitlab.com/DGothrek/ipyaggrid).  I have used both on JL3.